# New variable based on values from existing variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset where one variable is "ideology" with answers ranging from 1-10. I am looking to create a variable called "leftwing" for respondents who answered 1,2,3 or 4, with the end result being 1=leftwing, 0=not leftwing (anyone who answered 5,6,7,8,9,10)

I have tried this code:

```
examopg3 <- examopg2 %>%
  group_by(ideology) %>%
  mutate(leftwing = ideology == 1,2,3,4)
```

But the new variable only had the value "False" for all answers.

Thank you for helping me:)

Comment: `ideology == 1, 2, 3, 4` doesn’t do what you think it does. The correct way of writing this test is `ideology %in% (1 : 4)`. You *can* ad `case_when` as shown in the answer by Lucca but doing so isn’t necessary if you’re fine with a logical result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this:

```
 examopg3 <- examopg2 %>%
         mutate(leftwing = case_when(
                     ideology %in% c(1,2,3,4) ~ 1,
                     TRUE ~ 0))
```